# Long Delay in Calling the InCallScreen

Tags: android

Process outlined:

Why does the call to the new interface (`InCallScreen`) take such a long time? (From `TwelveKeyDialer` to `InCallScreen`).  This makes for a poor user experience.

First:

```
TwelveKeyDialer.java: 
      dialButtonPressed(){
         ...
         startActivity(intent);
      }
```

... why is the jump to the new interface (`InCallScreen`) slow?

Last:

```
InCallScreen.java:
      onCreate(){
       ...
      }
```